# Cannot deploy Sharepoint Solution

Tags: sharepoint-online, deployment, time-out

On my Development Tenant used for 1 year, I have problems with the deployment of my SharePoint AddIn Hosted Apps:

- No error when creating the package of the application to deploy (in Visual Studio)
- Successful deployment without errors
- The version number of the application is up to date
- JS files are not up-to-date

In addition, the deployment is very slow and frequently falls into timeout.

Thanks for the help.